# Cannot connect to SoundWire server on Windows 11

Tags: windows-11

I used to use [SoundWire Audio Communication System](https://georgielabs.net/) on Windows 10 without any problem. Now I got Windows 11 and my android phone (that works with SoundWire on Windows 10) is not able to connect.

- I tried to turn off Windows firewall.
- I followed official https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GwtOeGhGqtA solution by the author
- I tried to enter IP address of the server manually

But nothing worked. Is anyone using SoundWire on Windows 11 successfully and could help?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't watched the video you linked, so I don't know what he said there (I prefer text, as videos take way too long to get to the important information).

But I had the same problem, and it turned out to simply be that I hadn't registered the wireless network on the computer as private. By default, wi-fi networks are registered as public, and then you can't reach SoundWire. As soon as I set the network to be a private network, I could connect to SoundWire.

I'm unsure, though, if turning off the Windows Firewall as you tried has the same effect, so I can't say for certain if that is the problem.

Comment: thank you for the comment. I will try your suggestion once I got Win11 computer again.